# Marklogic MLCP java class path configuration for windows 10

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp, marklogic-9

I need to configure classpath for MLCP tool in Windows 10 system.Can anyone please let me know what is the configuration to include in the classpath and system variables?If you have a sample path configuration, Please provide it to me.

Comment: The distribution zip available at https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp includes a batch script for invoking MLCP from command-line. Can you use that?

Comment: I am using windows operating system and Mlcp.bat file . The problem with that configuration , I have to copy my Mlcp script inside the Mlcp folder . Then only I can run my ingestion script to load the data. If I configure my class path in system variables, I can be able to run the script through command line  from any drive. I tried in my local and it’s not working . So am looking for some help .